# Not getting the actual filepath from getpath() and unable to load .gItf file from local on by using AR Core[Android Begginer]

Tags: android, arcore

I am working on an AR app which enables the user to upload the .gItf file they downloaded in their phone local storage and place it on AR with Android AR Core.

However, i faced some issues....

1) I can't get the file path about the .gItf file

Isit because of the permission issue?

How I let the user upload file

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {

       Intent intent = new Intent();
       intent.setType("*/*");
       intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

       //To start a activity that will return result
       startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_FILES);
       //startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select your .gITF"),PICK_FILES);
}
```

How I try to get the path name

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if(requestCode==PICK_FILES && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data != null){

            path = data.getData().getPath();

            System.out.println(path);

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please select a valid file",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
}
```

My manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

What the printIn returns`content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc=2;doc=encoded=Wsi4zjmWYALAW/AO7bh0PsFGouCMhVw4QQj3XtHR36/iUIjd` instead of something with `file//xxxx.gItf`

Any solutions? Really need help as I browse alot of online resources but it did not work....

Comment: `can't get the file path about the .gItf file`. The 'file path'  is the content scheme `data.getData().toString()`.

Comment: What would be a 'path name' ? Do you mean a file name?

Comment: I mean something ends with .gitf >< instead of /document/xxxxx

Comment: You are supposed to react on my first comment too. Start with telling the value.

Comment: The URI you get back from a ACTION_GET_CONTENT intent is a content URI, not a file URI. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics#ContentURIs

Comment: So how can I use the content URI to use the model?

Comment: Hi @blackapps sorry I didn't notice your first comment at first

Do you mean that I can get my file path by changing the code to data.getData().toString()?

Comment: Repeat: `Start with telling the value`.

Comment: my 'path name' mean by file path. I am sorry if I offended anything but I am trying my best to tell the problem I face as well as I can...

Comment: You still did not tell the value of data.getData().toString().

Comment: Oh thats what you mean okk sorry I don't get it inititially. The value is ```content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D2%3Bdoc%3Dencoded%3DWsi4zjmWYALAW%2FAO7bh0PsFGouCMhVw4QQj3XtHR36%2FiUIjd```

Comment: @blackapps Is there any way to get the file path ? I go thru alot of readings and most of it they solve it with mediastorage, but I am using a 3D model which is a .gItf file and not photo or video or document

And I found that contentresolver, should I use that in this situation too?

The value after getData().toString() that you suggest is ```content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D2%3Bdoc%3Dencoded%3DWsi4zjmWYALAW%2FAO7bh0PsFGouCMhVw4QQj3XtHR36%2FiUIjd```

Comment: You have a nice content scheme. There is no 'the file path'. There is no 'file path'. For what do you need a file path? Use content resolver to open an inputstream on your scheme. Then you can read the model.